# How to integrate google map in automotive apps in android?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-automotive

I integrated google map into our android application. If I run the app in the Nexus 5X emulator it loading fine; no issue is observed. When I run the same app in the android automotive emulator..once the application is launched and showing as a google play services are updating but at the same time map not loading.

Can anyone tell me what is the issue? Is it possible to integrate google maps into the automotive platform?

below is my code

```
    public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;
private ActivityMapsBinding binding;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    binding = ActivityMapsBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    setContentView(binding.getRoot());

    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Google Map is part of GAS which is not open source and it's Google proprietary.To get access Company shall have partnership with Google

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).